# User account gone after flash install

Tags: macos, adobe-flash

Has anyone had an issue where their Mac user account has disappeared after installing flash player?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the Flash player from? Adobe's own web site, or a pop-up telling you it was out of date?

Comment: I’m 100% certain it was from adobe - https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: @Matt So what are you left with on the Mac ? How many user accounts ? Is there any Data left ? P.S. no-one should download flash.

Comment: Also, which version of macOS are you running? Does the user still show up in Preferences->Users&Groups, or when running `ls -l /Users` in Terminal`?

Comment: It turns out this is a false alarm. Following a restart a queued update made in error by my IT dept mean't that the user account had be deactivated - Thanks for your input otherwise

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is a false alarm. Following a restart a queued update made in error by my IT dept mean't that the user account had be deactivated - Thanks for your input otherwise